# Bluemix public CF App protect/private REST Endpoint

Tags: rest, security, ibm-cloud

I have a **public** Bluemix CF APP which exposes a REST Service. I would like to have the option, that the public url bound to the CFApp would be inaccessible from outside. The REST Service itself should only be usable from other CF Apps in my org, for example over API Management. I don't want to implement an own security mechanism for it, because API Management provides already everything I need to control, which clients will access my service. So some kind of private route inside Bluemix public, only available to runtimes and services in my Bluemix organisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible with IBM Bluemix, due to limitations in Cloud Foundry.

*All bound routes are accessible from the external network.*

If you want to have a private API exposed, you have the following options.

- Add authentication to the REST API, managing the credentials as a user-provided service bound to all the apps. The API will be accessible externally but only by users with the credentials.
- Use an application service, like a message queue, to expose an internal RPC-style API. Applications can bind to the same service and it will only be accessible internally.

Comment: Additional point of clarification - this is a limitation in CloudFoundry, not just Bluemix.